IntelliJ remote deployment to Payara 5 server auto undeploys after disconnect
I am deploying to a remote Payara 5 server using the intellij run configurations. Everything works great, except that after I stop the run configuration, the application undeploys. I have seen the explanation of a configuration option for Weblogic where intellij has a specific configuration for leave application deployed after disconnect, but I do not see any such checkbox for Payara/Glassfish. I haven't been able to find any option in the Payara admin panel for leaving it connected either. Am I just not seeing it or is this object better hidden than my searching abilities?
Thank you in advance
